Can I drag text into Emacs on MS Windows?
I would like to drag text from various programs into Emacs, in the same manner that one does when dragging text from (say) Firefox into (say) MS Word. That is, highlight the text in Firefox, then drag it into Word. The text appears at the location of the pointer. Is possible to have the same UX on Emacs in Windows 10/11?
I saw this relevant section of the manual, but I think it's saying that Windows is unsupported.

I'm afraid it cannot.  So... just use clipboard.
